# Update using two tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to update one date from a mysql table, using value from another table .

I'm trying to do execute this on my mysql server,

**Update**

```
update wp_posts post 
  join wp_postmeta meta 
    on post.ID = meta.post_id 
   set post.post_date = meta.false_date 
 where meta.false_date <> '';
```

But I get the following error on terminal

**Error**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from wp_posts post, wp_postmeta meta where post.ID = meta.post_id and meta.false' at line 1
```

**Meta**

```
|    7647 |    1483 | false_date                    | 2016-12-30
```

**SQL Sentence**

```
update wp_posts post 
  join wp_postmeta meta 
    on post.ID = meta.post_id 
   set post.post_date = meta.false_date 
 where meta.false_date <> '';
```

**Error 2**

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'meta.false_date' in 'where clause'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciate,

Jaster.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax looks like this:

```
update post p join
       meta m
       on p.id = m.post_id
    set p.post_date = m.false_date 
    where m.false_date <> '';
```

Notes:

- `update` in MySQL does not support a `FROM` clause.
- You should be using proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Use single quotes for string and date constants -- and nothing else.
- The standard SQL operator for inequality is `<>`.
- If `false_date` is properly stored as a date, then your comparison should be meaningless.  Perhaps you just intend:  `where false_date is not null`.

Comment: Now I have another error on my terminal `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'meta.false_date' in 'where clause'`. Also I updated the question, with some information, not all entries has `false_date` value.

Comment: @IsmaelMoral . . . You need to replace it with `m.false_date`.